# Determining if a solution set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

How do I go about proving that the solution set of

\begin{align*}
    w - 3 x + 4 y - z &= 0 \\
    3 w + x + 2 y + z &= 0
\end{align*}

is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

I originally defined S as:
\begin{equation}
S = \left\{ ( w, x, y, z) \in \mathbb { R } ^ { 4 } | w - 3x + 4y -z = 0\textbf{ and }3w + x + 2y + z = 0 \right\} 
\end{equation}

and then determined if

$\vec{0} \in S,$

$S$ is closed under addition ($u,\>v \in S \implies u + v \in S$), and

$S$ is closed under scalar multiplication ($\alpha \in \mathbb{F} \text{ and } u \in S \implies \alpha \cdot u \in S $),

by checking if both $w - 3x + 4y -z = 0$ and $3w + x + 2y + z = 0$ satisfied the above conditions, which was rather straightforward.

Is that correct?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  If you showed those conditions are satisfied (e.g., if $w-3x+4y-z=0$ and $3w+x+2y+z=0$ then $\alpha w -3\alpha x+4 \alpha y-\alpha x=0$ and $3 \alpha w + \alpha x + 2 \alpha y + \alpha z = 0$), you're done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method would be to note that $S=\operatorname{ker}T$ where $T$ is represented by the following matrix (rel the standard basis) :

$\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&4&-1\\3&1&2&1\end{pmatrix}$.

The kernel of a linear transformation is always a subspace.